# Salesforce OOP and Query limits

Tags: apex

I am having trouble using OOP with Apex. In apex every field to be used must have been queried so passing an object is not enough since there might been field that are not available in the object. Currently, the only way I know to get around this is querying  the fields I need in my methods/classes but It increases the amount of queries. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Can you please clarify what it is you're asking and maybe add some examples?

Comment: I assume Daniel is not enjoying the way referencing an extra field in some business logic requires you to manually add that field to the data access class that does the query. So apart from the dynamic SOQL `select * from ...` are there any other effective patterns?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you start looking into Enterprise Patterns such as Separation of Concerns by Andrew Fawcett to help with understanding how to manage OOP. You can read more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns

There is great information on managing data access and ensuring that adding fields is an easy process across your codebase.

Comment: specifically the Selector Pattern: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Selector_Layer